# powershell displaying expression with data

Tags: powershell, csv, expression

I have the following script I am trying to run from a list of users email addresseses in a csv file but am not getting the output in the format I want. When I run the script, it displays the output with the expressions before it like this 
`@{SamAccountName=userssamname}` and `@{$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()=size}` for the Quota.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

I want the output to just display the samaccountname and the quota.

```
Get-Content C:\temp\Emailist3.csv |
    ForEach-Object {
      $samaccountname=Get-User $_ | Select sAMAccountName
      $quota = (Get-Mailbox $_ | Get-MailboxStatistics |  select-object {$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}) 

  $propList =@{ 
            "Quota"=$quota
            "SAM"=$samaccountname

            }

  New-Object PscustomObject -Property $propList


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-Object -ExpandProperty` will work for `$samaccountname`.

For `$quota`, you'll need to modify the line to get the value in MB properly. This method worked for me:

```
$quota = Get-Mailbox $_ | Get-MailboxStatistics |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value | For-EachObject {$_.ToMB()}
```

Comment: Kolbrr,

I tried your suggestion and that worked for the samaccountname however, I get an error when trying to use it with the TotalItemSize. It says the Property "$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()" cannot be found.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @tinybyte Wasn't able to leave comments until a minute ago (rep restrictions). Modified the answer to better address the question.

Comment: @user3415777 Updated the answer to include a method to get the value for `$quota` you're looking for.